# What is the maximum file size supported in Excel for PowerView Report

Tags: business-intelligence, excel-2013, office-2013, powerview

I need your help for the below listed question.

1. What is the Excel file size limit to render Power View Report in Excel 20013?
2. Can we create Power View Report without including model data into Excel 2013?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

1. There is no published limitation for Excel 64bit PowerPivot. The limit is the RAM on your machine. The more RAM you have the bigger the model you can fit. Bear in mind that the data model is compressed because of vertipaq storage. This could be as high as 10:1 which means that data that would have have taken up 100MB in Excel sheets could take up as little as 10MB in the data model. The limit for Excel 32bit PowerPivot is [2GB](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Data-Model-specification-and-limits-19aa79f8-e6e8-45a8-9be2-b58778fd68ef). If your data is in Excel sheets then the limit is [1m rows](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3) but there is no file size limit other than your machine spec.
2. Yes you can. You can enable the Power View add-on while leaving the Power Pivot add-on disabled. You can still create Power Views from your Excel data. You can also create Power Views [from external sources](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Create-a-Power-View-sheet-connected-to-an-external-data-model-in-Excel-a721eb07-159e-488d-bcb1-804eb86040e0?CorrelationId=847e9054-4629-47c7-8a19-2e10d9fa5f96&ui=en-US&rs=en-IE&ad=IE&fromAR=1).

Answer (score 0):

As explained by Rory, Excel has a limitation of 1 million rows and the efficiency with which it can process Excel computations depends on the power of your machine. Big files can cause your average office desktop/laptop to freeze and Excel can crash too. It’s important to remember that Excel was originally built for accountants and not for data scientists. You should check out DataScout, a data discovery tool that is so easy to use that it doesn’t require any ninja coding skills. Just point and click and DataScout will automatically wrangle with your data to find hidden correlations and produce a range of charts. Check it out at http://www.datascout.ai